# Some php command does not work into html code

Tags: php, html, linux, ssh

I'm writing a php script in which I created an array from a stream straight from another php script running on a linux server, like this:

```PHP
$connection_portalemis = ssh2_connect('192.168.34.77', 22);
    // echo $connection_portalemis;
ssh2_auth_password($connection_portalemis, 'usr', 'pwd');
$controllikd4 = ssh2_exec($connection_portalemis, '/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/php/kd4check_new/controllikd4.php');
stream_set_blocking($controllikd4,true);
    
$arraySOA=array();
$i = 0;
while(!feof($controllikd4)) {   
  $arraySOA[$i] = stream_get_line($controllikd4, 0, "\n");
  $i            = $i+1;
```

I want to put the value of the array into an html, that I assign to a variable called $out, where I put other variables and where $out is the body of an email I have to send to me:

```PHP
$out = "<html>
  <body>
    <table> 
      <tr> $spiegazione </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table align=center >
      <tr align: center>
        <td> $result_DP </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table align=center >   
      <tr>
        <td> $result_Java </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table align=center>    
      <tr>
        <td> $result_JavaZ </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table align=center>    
      <tr>
        <td> $result_EAP </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table align=center>    
      <tr>
        <td> $result_legacy </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
<?php foreach($arraySOA as $key=>$value): ?>
      <tr> 
        <td> <?= $value; ?> </td>
      </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>";
```

But the issue is that the script gives me the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: key in C:\Manutenzione\confronti_itcam\confronti_itcam_main.php on line 126

> Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\Manutenzione\confronti_itcam\confronti_itcam_main.php on line 128

> Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\Manutenzione\confronti_itcam\confronti_itcam_main.php on line 133

I get the other variable correctly, but the values of the array not. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You can't put PHP tags in a PHP variable like that. `$out = "<?php echo 'foo'; ?>";` won't execute the PHP instructions.

Comment: You can't expect running PHP code on a Browser, because it's on client side, not server side.

Comment: Ok, so how to assign every value of the array to a single variable respecting the formatting? If I use a foreach cycle, at every cycle the variable is overwritten every time....is there a way to append the array values into a variable?